# Salesforce: URL Rewriter & JScript Remoting: Exception parsing json response: 'Unexpected token <'. Logged in?

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting, salesforce, remoting, visualforce

I am getting an error when I use JavaScript remoting and have my URLReWriter turned on on my Force.com SIte.  The error does not occur when using JavaScript Remoting with the URL ReWriter turned off.

The error is as follows

Exception Error parsing json response: 'Unexpected token <'. Logged in?

I'm confused as to why this is occuring. If I have no checks for being logged in in my URL ReWriter (or visualforce page) why should this occur?

Has anyone ever come across something similar to this before?  I noted  the following https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4112/possible-oauth-remote-action-bug but in my case I am not using authentication on my site for the test page that I created & I'm wondering why it mentions "login".

Is it possible that URLRewriters and JavaScript Remoting currently do not work together in general?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Can you try debugging it server side? Add "your_site_name Guest User" to the debug logs and try the action. If you're lucky you'll see something going wrong (in the remote action? in rewriter?) and I suspect this uncaught problem causes a redirect to maintenance page (which will be HTML, not JSON)...
2. If not - use Firebug or similar tool to inspect request & response in detail? Or `event.status`?
3. Can it be something related to permissions? http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm Or if you're returning html - I think you should have `{escape:true}`?
4. Does it happen in any browser? Maybe something doesn't like redirects caused by the URL rewriter. I've seen cases (not with Salesforce though) that antivirus software sometimes was adding some strange javascript at the end of certain websites and they had to be whitelisted...

Answer (score 0):

The error may also happen due to parser error when page recieves status message from remote action function.

For example i tried Remote Action with attachment

```
@RemoteAction

public attachment attach(String body){
 attachment a=new attachment();
 a.body=body;
 a.name='a.png'

 insert a;

return a;

 }
```

On the above code i receive error since SFDC does not parse the attachment object.SO if there are parser errors we get this message .

As a workaround i send as a wrapper .Hence i would suggest to investigate the return parameter of remote action and also wrapping it as workaround .

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Mohith,  thank you for your suggeestion and help.  A colleague of mine managed to find the solution.

Comment: In my URL Rewriter "global PageReference mapRequestUrl(PageReference rewrittenUrl){" function if I set my pagereference as "PageReference returnPageReference = Page.MyPage;"  the url rewriting will work for everything except the remote funciton.
For the Javascript remote action the pagereference should not have "/apex/MyPage" therefore thinking it needs to be logged in to function via apex pages.
 
To get around this use ""PageReference returnPageReference = new PageReference('../MyPage');" when setting the pagereference to return for a remote action.